# how to write the current system time to a csv file using python

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have a list of people and want to track their attendance each time a person is recognized. I have written the name to a csv file how to write their corresponding time also .

code:

```
for i in face_names:
    if "Unknown" in i:
        pass
    else:
        temp_mul_list.append(i)
print(str(temp_mul_list))
with open("res.csv", "w", newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for i in temp_mul_list:
        writer.writerow([i])
```

where **temp_mul_list** contains the names of the persons identified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what your code could look like

```
import datetime
for i in face_names:
    if "Unknown" in i:
        pass
    else:
        temp_mul_list.append([i, str(datetime.datetime.now())])
print(str(temp_mul_list))
with open("res.csv", "w", newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for i in temp_mul_list:
        writer.writerow(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the system time, use this code:

```
from datetime import datetime
time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

You can then pass `time` to `writer.writerow`.